# Encrypting PDF using .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes

I implemented a class to encrypt PDFs using .NET framework as explained in the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx). It has used `AESManaged` algorithm to do the encryption.

That method works perfectly and I was able to encrypt the document. But my problem is I was not able to open that file using any PDF viewer. According to my knowledge using any AES compliant PDF viewer we should be able to open the PDF after providing the key used to encrypt the document.

I tried with Adobe 11.0.02, Preview 6.0.1, PDFView 0.14.3, Skim 1.4.3 and Google Chrome. But they each detect that the files are corrupted. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

I have added the code below:

```
using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
{
  aesAlg.Key = Key;
  aesAlg.IV = IV;

  // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
  ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

  // Create the streams used for encryption. 
  using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
      using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
      {

        //Write all data to the stream.
        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
      }
      encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. I did the exactly the same way mentioned in the example. See the updated question

Comment: (The alternative is bugs in all the viewers, which is *very* doubtful. Also it might not be an issue with the encryption, but other handling of the data. For instance, are there non-encrypted headers or framing used with encrypted PDFs?)

Comment: Actually there may be a bug in the code. But I did the exactly same way in the example. @user2246674 I actually don't know the way .NET framework implement theAesManaged algorithm.

Comment: @ganuke AES is AES. As long as the correct parameters are used (e.g. IV, mode) then it will work *the same* as any other valid AES implementation. The other bit is to make sure the same (padded) key strategy is used, of course. (I have a feeling that the posted answer contains the basis for why the naive encryption doesn't work; if the encryption was just wrong I'd imagine the PDF to be displayed either in a very useless manner or a more specific encryption-error to be displayed.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code implies your approach to this problem has been to encrypt the entire PDF file. If so, then I think that over-simplification is the cause of your problem.

Most encrypted data formats have some form of cleartext header or trailer that allows recipients to check for flags and metadata that help with the decryption. Based on a brief bit of research, I found [this page](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/Adobe/Gallery/anon21jul01-pdf-encryption.txt) which suggests PDF encryption is no different.

Rather than a blanket encryption of the entire document bytes, the process is very specific. From the linked document:

> All stream (and string) objects in the PDF file are encrypted.  This
>   is sufficient to render the file useless (that is, if it weren't so
>   easy to decrypt).  Stream/string decryption works like this:
>
> 1. Take the 5-byte file key (from above).
> 2. Append the 3 low-order bytes (LSB first) of the object number
>         for the stream/string object being decrypted.
> 3. Append the 2 low-order bytes (LSB first) of the generation
>         number.
> 4. MD5 hash that 10-byte string.
> 5. Use the first 10 bytes of the output as an RC4 key to decrypt
>         the stream or string.  (This apparently still meets the US
>         export regulations because it's a 40-bit key with an additional
>         40-bit "salt".)